# Verb to be repetition in Yes/No questions

Tags: word-order, questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support

All,

Why don't we repeat is or are in questions starting with is or are (verb to be)? for example:

Is it (is) your glass?

Are you (are) taller than me?

How does it sound grammatically? Also, Does it change the overall tone of speaking (e.g., add emphasis, ...)?

Thanks

Comment: Because the question simply inverts the subject-verb order. "It is your glass" is a statement, "Is it your glass?" is the corresponding question.

Comment: Seems like a dupe of: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532514/word-order-in-question-with-do-you-think-and-do-you-know

Comment: Have you seen these examples? Are you used to "Is it is" from another language?

Comment: None of these are grammatical. If you dropped the question word, e.g. "It is your glass?" or "You are taller than me?", people would probably know what you meant (as long as you raised the tone at the end of the spoken sentence to indicate that it is a question and not a statement), but it will still be ungrammatical. The truth is, you need that question word at the beginning in order to make a question, and it always goes <Question word> <Subject> <Condition>. There are many question words, such as What/When/Where/Why/How/Does/Is/Are.

Comment: @YosefBaskin No, I haven't, but I see it sometime in Google research suggestions. Also, I often find myself using the "is it is" form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it is ___?" or "Are you are ___?" is grammatically incorrect.  It does not add emphasis or change the tone, it just sounds wrong and non-fluent.

When asking questions using the verb *to be*, you only use the verb once.  The only exception is if you are asking about a passive construction and using a participle:
You *are being* served. / *Are* you *being* served?

I don't think there's a "why" answer beyond "Because English is like that."